# How to set multiple keys to expire at different times?

Tags: redis, node-redis

Is there a better way to set multiple keys to expire at different times without having to set expiration of each individual one?
Here's an example to explain my quesiton better :

```
redis.mSet(["key1", "value1", "key2", "value2"])
redis.expire("key1", 1000)
redis.expire("key2", 2000)
//set them both to expire in a single query?
```

Comment: You can pipeline requests... https://github.com/redis/redis-py

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is the right solution. I would enhance it with two things:

1. Use transactions (multi/exec) so it will all be treated by the server as a single command.
2. Use pipeline so the perf impact will be minimal when using multiple commands (I think it is done automatically when using Node-Redis)

Comment: You are correct on point #2. Node Redis will automatically pipeline calls that you don't await.